# How do I set up global (or at least my street) Multiplayer in gamemaker studio 2?

Tags: multiplayer, game-maker-studio-2

To put it simply: How do I connect to my friends that live a few blocks away? (I have just started to learn how to make multiplayer games)
All the tutorials I've seen just say "we'll connect to local host for now" and then never come back to it.

Do I need to just change the server_ip to something specific or do I need to completely redo the networking?
Will my IPv4 work as server_ip for this?

Here is some of my code:

```
    // o_client - Create Event
    #macro PORT 45000

    server_ip = "127.0.0.1"
    socket = network_create_socket(network_socket_tcp);
    connect = network_connect(socket, server_ip, PORT);
```

```
    // o_server - Create Event
    server = network_create_server(network_socket_tcp, PORT, MAX_CLIENTS);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I Got it to work!
The problem was you need to set server_ip to your router's ip adress (google what is my ip) and you need to set a port forwarding rule (type ipconfig in command prompt type default gateway into a web browser and set the port to send to my devices ip (ipconfig > IPv4))